# Division of two series expansions

Tags: sequences-and-series, ordinary-differential-equations, fourier-series

I have the two functions $u(x)$ and $v(x)$, both of which have known basis expansions $u(x) = \sum_n a_n f_n(x)$, $v(x) = \sum_n b_n f_n(x)$.

I would like to calculate the function

$w(x)=\frac{\sum_n a_n f_n(x)}{\sum_n b_n f_n(x)} = \sum_n c_n f_n(x)$

I know the function $w(x)$ to be singularity-free and well defined, but numerically, things fall apart when $v(x)$ is close to zero (ie. I can't get the coefficients $c_n$ by the usual method of forming inner products and employing orthogonality). Is there a way to expression the coefficients $c_n$ in terms of $a_n$, $b_n$?

Comment: Any more information on the $f_n$s?

Comment: They are solutions to a Sturm-Liouville type differential equation. The satisfy $\int f_m(x) f_n(x) dx = \delta_{mn}$. Is this what you were looking for? Any other information?